# How can I be free from fear of ban?

Tags: discussion, support

I got a warning of being banned from asking questions here. What can I do now? They tell that I have some previous questions not decorated.

Comment: **1.** read what the warning is telling you carefully **2.** [Learn how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). **3.** [Improve your existing questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5047578/rubel-dinira?tab=questions).

Comment: simply just read the guideline under help option on SO

Comment: Jon Skeet wrote a piece titled ["Writing the perfect question"](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Highly recommended reading!

Comment: **4**. Don't ask questions that have been asked many times before.

Comment: Easy, ask enough high quality questions that you would be so far ahead of the threshold that a bad question can't possibly bring you back down. *Like that mark twain interpreter user*.

Answer (score 4):

**Fear the question ban**

Every time you want to ask a question, think about the question ban, dwell on the question ban. Until you are one-hundred percent positive that your question cannot be improved any more, and that the question will not contribute to your question ban, do not post the question.

Once you get into the question ban, **you're most likely not going to get out**. In fact, you're probably going to stop trying to get out all together. If you choose to stop fearing the question ban, be prepared to get a cold dose of reality.

Fearing the question ban should be your driving force. It should be your goal to never even get close to the question ban. **Every singe time you ask a question, it should never gather any more than two down-votes.**

**What can you do avoid the question ban?**

- Edit. Edit your questions like you've never edited before. By time you finish, your question should be in the New York Times's Bestsellers list.
- Learn how to ask good questions. You should be able to post a question that rivals [Jon Skeet's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).
- **Fear the question ban**. Go back to the top of this post and read it again.

Comment: I disagree respectfully. Fearing the question ban is nice and all (if it compels users to refrain from posting bad questions), but a regular user should just follow the guidelines laid out in [ask] carefully and will never get close or hit the question ban.

Comment: @Magisch I get where your coming from, but I don't really agree with your conclusion. Why should "regular users" think differently(assuming that you and I are using the same definition for a regular user)? Why could this not apply to everyone? Yes this might seem harsh for "regular users", but I'd rather someone be harsh to me in one post than to end up in a question ban(And you do know I was being sarcastic in parts of my answer right?).

Comment: I was thinking regular user in terms of posting enough that they could even potentially trigger the question ban. You can't hit the question ban with 1 or 2 questions, so "regular user" really refers to everyone for whom it matters. The bottom line is, the question ban rarely if ever hits users who carefully craft their questions and abide by the principles laid out in [ask].

Comment: @Magisch Well if that's your view on the matter, I can respect that and move on.

Comment: @Magisch, if someone has gotten a *warning* about being banned, then this answer applies to that person 100%.